# angularjs passing value for object

Tags: angularjs, object

```js
$scope.passingValueForObject = function(which, value) {
  $scope.object.which.push(value);
}
```

I want use "which" to push that want index. 
how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following syntax where "which" is the key of the object:

```
$scope.object[which].push(value);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.object.which = []
$scope.passingValueForObject = function(which, value) {
  $scope.object.which.push(value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, if it's only one object, you can just do this:

```
var ctrl = this;

this.passingValueForObject = function(obj, value) {
  ctrl.obj.attr = value;
}
```

Now, if we're talking about an array of objects, you can do this:

```
var ctrl = this;

this.objs = [ obj1{}, obj2{} ];

this.passingValueForObject = function(objs, index, value) {
  ctrl.objs[index].attr = value;
}
```

Comment: @DataHerder, like the way it's writted here, yes.
There isn't supposed to have the words obj1 and obj2 here, if you remove it'll work (I just leaved it that way to be more easy to see).